# Grid Lines disappear when adding html table

Tags: qgis, html

I'm using QGIS Las Palmas and currently wanted to add an html tables to map composer.

This is how my html looks like in a browser: [image]

Now, adding it to map composer through html, the lines now disappear.Any sugestions why does it behave like this?: [image: The grid lines are now invisible]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 plus MathML 2.0//EN"                              "http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/xhtml-math11-f.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!--This file was converted to xhtml by LibreOffice - see http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core/tree/filter/source/xslt for the code.--><head profile="http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8"/><title xml:lang="en-US">- no title specified</title><meta name="DCTERMS.title" content="" xml:lang="en-US"/><meta name="DCTERMS.language" content="en-US" scheme="DCTERMS.RFC4646"/><meta name="DCTERMS.source" content="http://xml.openoffice.org/odf2xhtml"/><meta name="DCTERMS.issued" content="2016-10-28T14:43:09.889080933" scheme="DCTERMS.W3CDTF"/><meta name="DCTERMS.modified" content="2016-11-14T17:42:41.322828400" scheme="DCTERMS.W3CDTF"/><meta name="DCTERMS.provenance" content="" xml:lang="en-US"/><meta name="DCTERMS.subject" content="," xml:lang="en-US"/><link rel="schema.DC" href="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" hreflang="en"/><link rel="schema.DCTERMS" href="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" hreflang="en"/><link rel="schema.DCTYPE" href="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/" hreflang="en"/><link rel="schema.DCAM" href="http://purl.org/dc/dcam/" hreflang="en"/><style type="text/css">
@page {  }
table { border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; empty-cells:show }
td, th { vertical-align:top; font-size:10pt;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { clear:both }
ol, ul { margin:0; padding:0;}
li { list-style: none; margin:0; padding:0;}
<!-- "li span.odfLiEnd" - IE 7 issue-->
li span. { clear: both; line-height:0; width:0; height:0; margin:0; padding:0; }
span.footnodeNumber { padding-right:1em; }
span.annotation_style_by_filter { font-size:95%; font-family:Arial; background-color:#fff000;  margin:0; border:0; padding:0;  }
* { margin:0;}
.ta1 { writing-mode:lr-tb; }
.Default { font-family:Liberation Sans; }
.ce1 { font-family:Times New Roman; border-bottom-width:0.0133cm; border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-color:#000000; border-left-width:0.0133cm; border-left-style:solid; border-left-color:#000000; border-right-width:0.018cm; border-right-style:solid; border-right-color:#000000; border-top-width:0.0133cm; border-top-style:solid; border-top-color:#000000; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center ! important; font-size:12pt; font-style:normal; text-shadow:none; text-decoration:none ! important; font-weight:bold; }
.ce10 { font-family:Liberation Sans; border-style:none; font-size:11pt; font-style:normal; text-shadow:none; text-decoration:none ! important; font-weight:normal; }
.ce2 { font-family:Times New Roman; border-bottom-width:0.0133cm; border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-color:#000000; border-left-width:0.0133cm; border-left-style:solid; border-left-color:#000000; border-right-width:0.018cm; border-right-style:solid; border-right-color:#000000; border-top-width:0.0133cm; border-top-style:solid; border-top-color:#000000; text-align:center ! important; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal; text-shadow:none; text-decoration:none ! important; font-weight:normal; }
.ce3 { font-family:Times New Roman; border-bottom-width:0.0133cm; border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-color:#000000; border-left-width:0.0133cm; border-left-style:solid; border-left-color:#000000; border-right-width:0.018cm; border-right-style:solid; border-right-color:#000000; border-top-width:0.0133cm; border-top-style:solid; border-top-color:#000000; text-align:justify ! important; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal; text-shadow:none; text-decoration:none ! important; font-weight:bold; }
.ce4 { font-family:Times New Roman; border-bottom-width:0.0133cm; border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-color:#000000; border-left-width:0.0133cm; border-left-style:solid; border-left-color:#000000; border-right-width:0.018cm; border-right-style:solid; border-right-color:#000000; border-top-width:0.0133cm; border-top-style:solid; border-top-color:#000000; text-align:justify ! important; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal; text-shadow:none; text-decoration:none ! important; font-weight:normal; }
.ce5 { font-family:Liberation Sans; }
.ce6 { font-family:Times New Roman; border-bottom-width:0.0133cm; border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-color:#000000; border-left-width:0.0133cm; border-left-style:solid; border-left-color:#000000; border-right-width:0.018cm; border-right-style:solid; border-right-color:#000000; border-top-width:0.0133cm; border-top-style:solid; border-top-color:#000000; text-align:center ! important; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal; text-shadow:none; text-decoration:none ! important; font-weight:bold; }
.ce7 { font-family:Times New Roman; border-bottom-width:0.0133cm; border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-color:#000000; border-left-width:0.0133cm; border-left-style:solid; border-left-color:#000000; border-right-width:0.018cm; border-right-style:solid; border-right-color:#000000; border-top-width:0.0133cm; border-top-style:solid; border-top-color:#000000; text-align:center ! important; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal; text-shadow:none; text-decoration:none ! important; font-weight:normal; }
.ce8 { font-family:Liberation Sans; border-style:none; font-size:11pt; font-style:normal; text-shadow:none; text-decoration:none ! important; font-weight:bold; }
.ce9 { font-family:Liberation Sans; border-style:none; font-size:11pt; font-style:normal; text-shadow:none; text-decoration:none ! important; font-weight:normal; }
.co1 { width:240.69pt; }
.co2 { width:89.86pt; }
.co3 { width:77.9pt; }
.co4 { width:64.01pt; }
.co5 { width:297.55pt; }
.ro1 { height:15pt; }
.ro2 { height:13.8pt; }
.ro3 { height:12.81pt; }
<!-- ODF styles with no properties representable as CSS -->
 { }
</style></head><body dir="ltr" style="writing-mode:lr-tb; "><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="ta1"><colgroup><col width="371"/><col width="139"/><col width="120"/><col width="99"/><col width="99"/><col width="99"/><col width="459"/><col width="99"/></colgroup><tr class="ro1"><td colspan="3" style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce1"><p>Places where Households Evacuated during Yolanda and Ruby </p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce8"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce8"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro2"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce2"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce6"><p>Typhoon Yolanda </p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce6"><p>Typhoon Ruby </p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro2"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce3"><p>Within Batang </p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce10"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro2"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce4"><p>Batang Elementary School then transferred to a cave</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce10"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro2"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce4"><p>Batang elementary school</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro2"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce4"><p>Stayed at home, went to neighbor’s house</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce10"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro2"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce4"><p>Cave/mountain</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce10"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro2"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce4"><p>Tent/kulong</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce10"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro2"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce3"><p>Outside Batang</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce10"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro2"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce4"><p>Private house – Padang</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce10"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro2"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce4"><p>Private house – Cancilides</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce10"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro2"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce4"><p>Private house – San Isidro</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce10"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro2"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce4"><p>Private house – San Miguel</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce10"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro2"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce4"><p>Private house – Carmen</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce10"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro2"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce4"><p>Cancilides day care center</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce10"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro2"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce4"><p>San Isidro ES</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce10"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro2"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce4"><p>Padang ES</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro2"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce4"><p>Day care center - Cancilides </p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce10"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce9"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro3"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce3"><p>Outside Hernani</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro3"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce4"><p>Private house – Llorente</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"><p>-</p></td><td style="text-align:right; width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"><p>2</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro3"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce4"><p>Private house – Borongan</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"><p>-</p></td><td style="text-align:right; width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"><p>1</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro3"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce3"><p>Others</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"><p>-</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"><p>-</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro3"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce4"><p>No data</p></td><td style="text-align:right; width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"><p>26</p></td><td style="text-align:right; width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"><p>-26</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro3"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce4"><p>Not in Batang during the typhoon</p></td><td style="text-align:right; width:89.86pt; " class="ce7"><p>5</p></td><td style="text-align:right; width:77.9pt; " class="ce7"><p>2</p></td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro3"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr><tr class="ro3"><td style="text-align:left;width:240.69pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:89.86pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:77.9pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:297.55pt; " class="ce5"> </td><td style="text-align:left;width:64.01pt; " class="ce5"> </td></tr></table></body></html>
```

Oh, the html code was a little bit long.

Comment: Please post your CSS, maybe a snippet of your HTML if possible. I suspect you need to add an explicit rule for table cell borders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce this issue on Qgis 2.18. I think the reason is that your lines are too narrow.

From experimenting using your HTML, it looks like any line which is

- < 1pt
- < 1px
- < 0.03cm

doesn't show up in an HTML Frame in QGIS Composer. Your mileage may vary depending on your monitor's dpi settings.

Lines thinner than this also don't show on exporting to SVG, PNG or PDF. Not sure what happens when you attempt to print, but I suspect they won't show up.

Not sure if this is an issue with QGIS or Qt...

Comment: I'd manually change the values to show the lines, a range of 0.05 to 0.07 cm works for me.